# Writing unicode/utf-8 data to a memory file

Tags: unicode, smalltalk, memorystream, pharo

How can one write unicode/utf-8 to a file in MemoryStore?

Normally I can just do the following

```
fs := FileSystem workingDirectory.
file := fs / 'file.txt'.
file writeStreamDo: [ :stream | stream << '彼得' ].
file contents. "'彼得'"
```

the `stream` there is a `MultiByteFileStream`.

However when I try to do the same on memory storage, I and up with an error

```
fs := FileSystem memory.
file := fs / 'file.txt'.
file writeStreamDo: [ :stream | stream << '彼得' ].
```

> Error: Improper store into indexable object

Because `stream` there is an ordinary `WriteStream`.

I've tried to work around it by directly instantiating `MultiByteFileStream`, however that seems to require real file.

Is there another way?

Comment: What encoding are you trying to produce? Depending on that you could first get the `ByteArray` encoding your unicode `String` and then send it to the `stream`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia the content should be in utf8

Comment: Then try `file writeStream nextPutAll: '彼得' utf8Encoded`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the memory file system doesn't handle multibyte files by default.  Try:

```
| fs file stream |

fs := FileSystem memory.
file := fs / 'file.txt'.
stream := MultiByteBinaryOrTextStream on: (fs open: file writable: true).
stream converter: UTF8TextConverter new.
[ stream << '彼得' ] ensure: [ stream close ].
file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expression that will do what you are looking for:

```
string := '彼得'.
file writeStreamDo: [:stream |
  #utf8 asZnCharacterEncoder
    next: string size
    putAll: string
    startingAt: 1
    toStream: stream]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(FileSystem memory root / 'foo.txt')
  writeStreamDo: [ :out |
    out binary.
    (ZnCharacterWriteStream on: out encoding: #utf8) << '彼得' ].
```

should work.